# How to install sharepoint server on windows server 2012 r2 steps

Tags: iis, sharepoint, prerequisites

I've been going around this for a couple of days now and the answer didn't seem to be anywhere so here it is, almost everything you will need to successfully run the prerequisites installer

Answer (score 0):

Once we have successfully installed windows server:

(software con be downloaded from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2013)

Run de prerequisites installer and wait for the messages.

We may have to install the components separately, they can be downloaded from Microsoft directly and these are all free or charge.

The list is what follows:

• Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
• Windows Management Framework 3.0
• **Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role**
• Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
• Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
• Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
• Windows Server AppFabric
• Microsoft Identity Extensions
• Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
• Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
• Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763

Most items can be downloaded from these links, you may wanna try some different ones in case the provided didn’t work:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/3/9138773A-505D-43E2-AC08-9A77E1E0490B/1033/x64/sqlncli.msi

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client

http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/0/0/E0060D8F-2354-4871-9596-DC78538799CC/Synchronization.msi

Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)

http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/7/A678AB47-496B-4907-B3D4-0A2D280A13C0/WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe

Windows Server App Fabric

http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/5/7B51D8D1-20FD-4BF0-87C7-4714F5A1C313/AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe

Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)

http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/7/2/D72FD747-69B6-40B7-875B-C2B40A6B2BDD/Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu

Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)

http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01D06854-CA0C-46F1-ADBA-EBF86010DCC6/rtm/MicrosoftIdentityExtensions-64.msi

Microsoft Identity Extensions

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/1/D/91DA8796-BE1D-46AF-8489-663AB7811517/setup_msipc_x64.msi

Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client

http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/9/8F93DBBD-896B-4760-AC81-646F61363A6D/WcfDataServices.exe

Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0

The “**Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role**” item may be the one that causes more trouble to install, in order to get it working in case the installer can’t handle it, we should run the following script from PowerShell:

```
Import-Module ServerManager

Copy-Item -Path "$($ENV:SystemRoot)\System32\ServerManager.exe" `
    -Destination "$($ENV:SystemRoot)\System32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -Force

Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45,NET-WCF-TCP-Activation45,NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45

Add-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Features,Web-Server,Web-WebServer, `
    Web-Common-Http,Web-Static-Content,Web-Default-Doc,Web-Dir-Browsing, `
    Web-Http-Errors,Web-App-Dev,Web-Asp-Net,Web-Net-Ext,Web-ISAPI-Ext, `
    Web-ISAPI-Filter,Web-Health,Web-Http-Logging,Web-Log-Libraries,Web-Request-Monitor, `
    Web-Http-Tracing,Web-Security,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Filtering, `
    Web-Digest-Auth,Web-Performance,Web-Stat-Compression,Web-Dyn-Compression, `
    Web-Mgmt-Tools,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Mgmt-Compat,Web-Metabase,Application-Server, `
    AS-Web-Support,AS-TCP-Port-Sharing,AS-WAS-Support, AS-HTTP-Activation, `
    AS-TCP-Activation,AS-Named-Pipes,AS-Net-Framework,WAS,WAS-Process-Model, `
    WAS-NET-Environment,WAS-Config-APIs,Web-Lgcy-Scripting,Windows-Identity-Foundation, `
    Server-Media-Foundation,Xps-Viewer

Restart-Computer
```

Once the reboot has finished, run the prerequisites installer again and there should be no warnings or trouble to conclude.

After the wizard ends, run the SharePoint server installer. The wizard should prompt for a product key, as this is a trial version, one of the following should work: NQTMW-K63MQ-39G6H-B2CH9-FRDWJ

After we add the key, click next, agree the license terms and a progress bar should come up. Go grab a smoke in this step... It may never end after a couple of hours. After maybe 30 minutes, you can check the log files, inside the Temp folder, in my case: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2

Scroll down to the end of 'SharePoint Server Setup(...)' file and check the status, mine is: 'Successfully installed package: oserver path:D:\global\oserver.MSI'

Restart your machine even with the wizard still running (it's not gonna end any time soon) and that's it.

Hope this helps you!